# Type of error in textboxes and checkboxes in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have multiple checkboxes and textboxes in 3 grids but i can't clear them.
Error is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' to
>   type 'System.Windows.Controls.Control

Yes, I have mutliple textblocks too but I don't want clear them.
I need to clear them in the userGrid.

**XAML structure:**

```
<Windows>
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <Grid x:Name="userGrid">
            <Textbox/>
            <Checkbox/>
            <Textblock/>
            ...
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="pcGrid">
            <Textbox/>
            <Checkbox/>
            <Textblock/>
            ...
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Windows
```

**Code:**

```
    foreach (Control c in _mainWindow.userGrid.Children)
    {
        if (c is TextBox && c != null) { ((TextBox)c).Text = string.Empty; }
    }
    foreach (Control c in _mainWindow.userGrid.Children)
    {
        if (c is CheckBox && c != null) { ((CheckBox)c).IsChecked = false; ((CheckBox)c).ClearValue(Control.ForegroundProperty); }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of `foreach (Control c ...` try `foreach (var c ...`, `TextBox` class does not inherit from `Control` class and this is the problem in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [TextBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textblock?view=netframework-4.7.2) class, it doesn't inherit from the `Control` class, so your `foreach` breaks because the `Children` list contains `TextBlock` elements and they cannot be cast as `Control`.

You could use Linq to fix that:

```
foreach(TextBox t in _mainWindow.userGrid.Children.OfType<TextBox>())
```

Comment: @EpicKip not sure I get your remark, I'm using `TextBox` in the example code.